# How to read from DOM and assign the value into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, django, xmlhttprequest

I have a specific id defined both in the DOM and another endpoint

The endpoint is `https://www.example.com/info/data` 
Data in the above endpoint is as shown below

```
{"config":{"user_id":"12345"}}
```

DOM contains the id as `"user_id": "12345"`

The user id is specified in the DOM

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window._sharedData = {
        "config": {
            "user_id": "12345",
            }
}
<script>
```

The above shown data is defined same in the previously mentioned endpoint.

I want to acquire the value of user_id from any of the above mentioned locations and assign the same to my form with the name userid

```html
<form>
<input type="hidden" name="userid" value="valueforuserid" />
</form>
```

My webapp is in django and I searched Django documentation for further information ,while searching I came across [Acquiring CSRF Token from DOM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/csrf/#acquiring-the-token-if-csrf-use-sessions-or-csrf-cookie-httponly-is-true).The documentation is mentioning a jquery form for fetching token as below

```
{% csrf_token %}
<script type="text/javascript">
// using jQuery
const csrftoken = jQuery("[name=csrfmiddlewaretoken]").val();
</script>
```

Can I use this jquery to fetch the same and assign this to my form . 
If yes how can I do that ? I am not good with jquery and js.

Comment: You do not show where in the DOM the `"user_id": "12345"` is found. Can you show more from "view-source" of the page where that would be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The jQuery you are posting is getting a token from an input field with the name of csrfmiddlewaretoken, it is not getting it from the server.

From your var:

```
window._sharedData = {
  "config": {
    "user_id": "12345",
  }
}
$(function() { // on page load
  $("[name=userid]").val(window._sharedData.config.user_id);
})
```

Using AJAX from the endpoint IIF the endpoint supports CORS:

```
$.get("https://www.example.com/info/data",function(data) {
  $("[name=userid]").val(data.config.user_id);
})
```

Comment: I am not good with AJAX as well , can you make a an answer with the html form to supply the user_id .The django documentation is saying "read the token from the DOM with JavaScript:". I have updated the question

Comment: If the data is already in the page as you show, then it is trivial to replace the code I wrote with the code from the existing var. See update

Comment: Do I need to use xhr for CORS request to fetch the data . I am having trouble executing the script

Comment: You do not need ajax at all if you have this already in the page `window._sharedData = {
  "config": {
    "user_id": "12345",
  }
}`

Comment: $.get IS xhr - just a short form. You may need $.post if that is how the endpoint responds

Comment: thanks , one will this replay the respective credentials  ? or do i need to specify it exclusively

Comment: I have no idea what you meant with what you just wrote

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218025/discussion-between-joel-deleep-and-mplungjan).